# Looking for an image change on mouseover link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know of a jquery plugin or a simple javascript which could allow me to change the image depending on the text link I hover over with a mouse.

The image is fixed in one spot, and the links are displayed below.  As I hover down the list of links, the image above changes.  Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post your HTML and the local URL to a few of the images.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a plugin for this. Using simple peiece of jQuery/javascript code you can achieve this.

Try this.

Assuming a simple markup like this

```
<img id="imgContainer" src="" />
<a href="image.png">Mouse over on me</a>
```

Js script

```
$("a").mouseover(function(){
    $("#imgContainer").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP wants text links and a common image.  I may be wrong.

With a list of links like

I think

```
<a href="location to go to here"
    onmouseover="document.NAME.src='picture for this link'"
    onmouseout ="document.NAME.src='orig-picture'">
link text
</a>
```

A common image would be

```
<img name=NAME src='orig-picture'>
```

that would be changed by any number of links.

EDIT: Is this what you want to do?

http://momarda.brinkster.net/simple_image_swap.asp

Comment: I found the script that does what I want it to do but I need some explaining on how it works.    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
function showT(q){ 
document.getElementById('ima').setAttribute('src','0'+q+'.jpg') 
} 
</script>

Comment: @user7039 -  I put a link in an edit.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: @user7039 Please accept this answer or provide additional information if this was not what you wanted.